# What are NIC MMIO regions used for?

Tags: networking, operating-system, nic

I'm confusing about the usage of NIC (Network interface card) MMIO regions.

For example, this is the information of a NIC on my computer

```
03:02.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Dual Port Server Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64 (63750ns min), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at e1b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 2: Memory at e1a40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at e1a00000 [disabled] [size=256K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
    Kernel modules: e1000
```

I can see that it has 2 MMIO regions.

At first I think that these 2 regions are used for receiving and sending packets, one is the RX buffer and another is the TX buffer, but after doing some test, I think that I was wrong.

So, what actually these MMIO regions are used for? And if they not the TX and RX buffers, where are these buffers?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you test what those regions are used for?

Comment: I use a hypervisor to disable cpu cores from accessing these MMIO regions. It can still receive/send packets, but after that if I try to disable the NIC and reenable it, my computer hangs up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *memory* base address registers (BARs). Here is an OSDev [explanation](http://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Base_Address_Registers) for the concept. Memory BARs usage is device-dependent and might be a subject for a separate talk. For instance, a PCI device may have a small BAR to provide access to whatever *registers* it has. Also, certain parts of device RAM may be exposed by means of larger BARs.

Your question is about NIC, so, indeed, one of the BARs in your example is a base HW address where NIC registers reside. `e1000` driver can query the address during PCI resource allocation step (it's a long talk, but, all in all, a suitable address resides in `hw_addr` [field](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_hw.h#L1351) of `struct e1000_hw`). And, during its operation, `e1000` may read from some registers or write to them using the mentioned address + some offset. You can find offsets for different registers defined in the [corresponding header](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_hw.h#L792). For instance, when the driver needs to manage, say, Tx ring, it may query/update its head or tail using the proper [registers](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_hw.h#L928). For example, you may take a look at how the driver [writes zeroes](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_main.c#L2014) there.

You also asked about Rx and Tx buffers location. It's not quite clear whether you mean *data* buffers. If so, I'm afraid, `lspci` may not be helpful since actually packet data is received and transmitted using host memory buffers and [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) (direct memory access) technique. For instance, if the driver wants to transmit a packet, it obtains the physical address of the buffer where the packet is stored (host memory) and prepares a so-called *descriptor* by [setting the packet buffer address](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_main.c#L2889) in it. The descriptor is then pushed to the device. As soon as the NIC gets the descriptor, it will initiate a DMA transaction, i.e. it will place a memory access request directly on the host memory and eventually it will read in the contents of the buffer to be transmitted.

So, I hope you find my short answer to be at least a little bit useful. And, of course, you may learn more from the driver source and some HW-related documents.